# Make text difficult to parse by automated means

Tags: javascript, regex, obfuscation

I need to include a small JavaScript snippet on my [single-page web-application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) that serves as a **content-protection mechanism** for subsequent AJAX-requests:

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
    DR.token.id = RANDOM_HASH
</script>
```

This protection has a flaw: it is trivially easy for a machine to extract the `RANDOM_HASH` part of the snippet.

To counter this, I use a simple server-side script to add some noise into the snippet, resulting in varying versions of:

```
document.write("<SCR" + "IPT>DR.toke" + "n.id" + " = " + "\"RANDO" + " + "M_HASH\"</" + "SCRIPT>"
document.write("<S" + "CRIPT>DR.t" + "oken.id" + " = " + "\"RAN" + " + "DOM_HASH\"</SCRI" + "PT>"
...
```

However, just a slightly more complex regex would successfully extract `RANDOM_HASH` once again.

I'd prefer not to use an on-the-fly obfuscator, since performance is vital. Are there any reliable solutions that would make it difficult for machines to extract the random hash without *significant* effort on their part?

**I'm not concerned about machines that are capable of running Javascript code to achieve this extraction, I only intend to deter the average Joe from writing a trivial script that would harvest my application's data.**

Comment: Does minification not obfuscate it enough?

Comment: @Tony Thing is, there isn't much to minify on this little snippet. It wouldn't make a significant difference, and the hash code would be still there.

Comment: If I saw something like `a.b.c=RANDOM_HASH` how would I even begin to know how to use it? Perhaps you'd be better off removing it from the DOM entirely and storing it in a cookie or local storage. Depending on your server, you could use middleware to encrypt/decrypt. Possibly look to [a more security-orientated SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must recognize that nothing you do on a web page will be secure to snooping. The best you can hope for is to defeat naive hacking techniques. To that extent, your "add some noise" approach is perfectly sound. Yes, it can be hacked with a "slightly more complex regex", but how is an attacker to know *which* regex that might be? It would take analyzing the source, which to my mind qualifies as significant effort.

If it will give you some added (but false) measure of security, you can base-64 encode (off line) the arguments to `document.write()` and decode them on the fly. I don't think that would have much performance impact. (Calling `document.write()` itself would, I think, swamp the decoding overhead.) It would certainly insulate your sensitive info from a human casually reading the page source. So, for instance, the base-64 encoding of

```
<script>DR.token.id = RANDOM_HASH</script>
```

is

```
PHNjcmlwdD5EUi50b2tlbi5pZCA9IFJBTkRPTV9IQVNIPC9zY3JpcHQ+
```

So your document could contain:

```
document.write(fromBase64('PHNjcmlwdD5EUi50b2tlbi5pZCA9IFJBTkRPTV9IQVNIPC9zY3JpcHQ+'));
```

where `fromBase64()` is your base-64 decoder.

Comment: Why would any "hacker" approach this with regex if the var consistently seems to be window.DR.token.id? I think the real question here is: what is OP trying to protect? Your efforts to hash a JS var seem a real waste of time.

Comment: @Jonathan I'm trying to protect all AJAX requests in my application, in a fashion that the aforementioned random hashcode is _only_ included on the index page, and without it, the XHR is denied by the server. This ensures that the machine utilizing my JSON API is guaranteed to also have the index page downloaded before subsequent communication. Should I add this to the question?

Comment: @Jonathan - Indeed. That's why I made the point that this is false security. However, I've found that it is very effective against automated email scrapers. (Adding "noise" as OP tried isn't as effective because email addresses have a distinctive pattern that can be recognized even in the presence of such noise.)